# How do I add just one extra node to a view? Display OG contents plus OG group node

Tags: views, organic-groups

I have created an ajax view that displays the contents of a group.  It shows one page at a time, with a nice jquery pageturn effect when you go to the next page.

I now want to insert the actual group node at the start of this view.  I can't put it in header or template files, as then it wont work with the ajax pagination.

I have worked out the SQL I need to get the results I want...

`SELECT node.nid AS nid FROM d7_node node
LEFT JOIN d7_og_membership og_membership_node ON node.nid = og_membership_node.etid AND        og_membership_node.entity_type = 'node'
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (og_membership_node.gid =   '42' ) )) OR (node.nid = '294')
ORDER ASC`

The SQL my view is currently using is...

`SELECT node.nid AS nid FROM d7_node node
LEFT JOIN d7_og_membership og_membership_node ON node.nid = og_membership_node.etid AND        og_membership_node.entity_type = 'node'
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (og_membership_node.gid =   '42' ) )) 
ORDER ASC`

So basically I just need to tag on  'OR (node.nid = '294')' to the WHERE.

I'm trying to use this custom module

```
function hook_views_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
if ($view->name == 'flipbook_ii') {
    $nid = $view->args['0'];
    $query->where[] = array(
      'conditions' => array(
        '0' => array(
          'field' => 'node.nid',
          'value' => $nid,
          'operator' => '=',
        ),
      ),
      'type' => 'OR',
    );
  }
}
```

But that is still setting the WHERE query

`WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (og_membership_node.gid = '42' ) AND (node.nid = '294') ))`

Can anyone explain a way that works?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while but eventually solved this....

Needed to add

$query->group_operator = 'OR';

into my hook_views_query_alter.

Comment: Cool that you got it working :) Please accept this as the answer, so the question gets removed from the unanswered queue.